# Roles y permisos a Usuarios en windows forms con entity framework

Tags: c#, windows-forms, entity-framework

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que se deshabilite (configuracion y produccion) cuando se ingrese con la sesion de un usuario x y que admin tenga todos los accesos. se plantea de esta manera ya que se tiene n cantidad de usuarios en la bd.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi login**

```
private void datos(string emp, string pass)
    {

         if (textuser.Text != "")
        {
            var result = from d in db.tblUsuario
                         where d.usuario == textuser.Text && d.password == textcontrase.Text
                         select d;

            int contador = result.Count();


            if (result.Count() == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no hay usuario");

            }
            else 
            {   

                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    string user = item.usuario;
                    int numero = item.perfilid;

                    var blogs = db.transPerfilRegla.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.transPerfilRegla where Perfilid = "+numero+"").ToList();
                    foreach (var query in blogs)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("numero de perfil id " + query.Perfilid + " regla numero: " + query.Reglaid);


                    }
                }

                Form1 obj = new Form1();

                obj.lblusuario.Text = textuser.Text;
                obj.Show();

                //this.Close();

            }
        }


    }
```

**mi boton el cual lleva a datos**

```
 private void aceptar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datos(textuser.Text, textcontrase.Text);
        //TieneRegla(regla);
        //datos();
    }
```

**al ingresar este es mi formulario principal, solo utilizo el load por el momento**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //lblusuario.Text;
        TieneReglas(lblusuario.Text);
        Formularios.Login adper = new Formularios.Login();

        adper.users = lblusuario.Text;

        archivoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = adper.TieneReglas("1");
        configureToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = adper.TieneReglas("2");
        if (archivoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled==true)
        {

            btncapturistaeditar.Visible = true;
        }
        if (configureToolStripMenuItem.Enabled== true)
        {
            btnconfiguracion.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Quiero que se deshabilite (configuracion y produccion) cuando se ingrese con la sesion de un usuario x y que admin tenga todos los accesos. se plantea de esta manera ya que se tiene n cantidad de usuarios en la bd

Comment: Nos puedes mostrar lo que llevas al momento por favor?

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta e indica en texto el código que has intentado realizar. 
Así será mas fácil ayudarte, y evitarás que te cierren la pregunta por baja calidad.

Comment: permiteme lo edito